# Graphics.Transform is massively inefficient, what can I do about this?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, graphics

I am writing a particle engine and have noticed it is massively slower than it should be (I've written highly un-optimized 3D C++ particle engines that can render 50k particles at 60 fps, this one drops to 32 fps at around 1.2k..), I did some analysis on the code assuming the rendering of the particles or the rotations were the most CPU intensive operation, however I discovered that in fact these two little properties of the graphics object are actually eating up over 70% of my performance....

```
    public void RotateParticle(Graphics g, RectangleF r, 
                                RectangleF rShadow, float angle, 
                                Pen particleColor, Pen particleShadow)
    {
        //Create a matrix
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        PointF shadowPoint = new PointF(rShadow.Left + (rShadow.Width / 1),
                                        rShadow.Top + (rShadow.Height / 1));
        PointF particlePoint = new PointF(r.Left + (r.Width / 1),
                                          r.Top + (r.Height / 2));
        //Angle of the shadow gets set to the angle of the particle, 
        //that way we can rotate them at the same rate
        float shadowAngle = angle;                
        m.RotateAt(shadowAngle, shadowPoint);

        g.Transform = m;

        //rotate and draw the shadow of the Particle
        g.DrawRectangle(particleShadow, rShadow.X, rShadow.Y, rShadow.Width, rShadow.Height);

        //Reset the matrix for the next draw and dispose of the first matrix
        //NOTE: Using one matrix for both the shadow and the partice causes one 
        //to rotate at half the speed of the other.
        g.ResetTransform();
        m.Dispose();

        //Same stuff as before but for the actual particle
        Matrix m2 = new Matrix();
        m2.RotateAt(angle, particlePoint);

        //Set the current draw location to the rotated matrix point
        //and draw the Particle
        g.Transform = m2;

        g.DrawRectangle(particleColor, r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
        m2.Dispose();
    }
```

What is killing my performance is specifically these lines:

```
g.Transform = m;
g.Transform = m2;
```

A little background, the graphics object is getting grabbed from painteventargs, it is then rendering particles to the screen in a render particles method, which calls this method to do any rotations, multi-threading isn't a solution as the graphics object cannot be shared between multiple threads. Here is a link to the code analysis I ran just so you can see what is happening as well:

https://gyazo.com/229cfad93b5b0e95891eccfbfd056020

I am kinda thinking this is something that can't really be helped because it looks like the property itself is destroying the performance and not anything I've actually done (though I'm sure there's room for improvement), especially since the dll the class calls into is using the most cpu power. Anyways, any help would be greatly appreciated in trying to optimize this...maybe I'll just enable/disable rotation to increase performance, we'll see...

Comment: Also I apologize for the image, I know it is really small, if you squint you can see the numbers though! :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you should scratch your head a while over the profile results you see.  There is something *else* going on when you assign the Transform property.  Something you can reason out by noting that ResetTransform() does not cost anything.  Doesn't make sense of course, that method also changes the Transform property.

And do note that it should be DrawRectangle() that should be the expensive method since that is the one that actually puts the pedal to the metal and generates real drawing commands.  We can't see what it cost from your screenshot, can't be more than 30%.  That is not nearly enough.

I think what you see here is an obscure feature of GDI/plus, it **batches** drawing commands.  In other words, internally it generates a list of drawing commands and does not pass them to the video driver until it has to.  The native winapi has an function that explicitly forces that list to be flushed, it is [GdiFlush()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  That is however not exposed by the .NET Graphics class, it is done automagically.

So a pretty attractive theory is that GDI+ internally calls GdiFlush() when you assign the Transform property.  So the cost you are seeing is *actually* the cost of a previous DrawRectangle() call.

You need to get ahead by giving it more opportunity to batch.  Very strongly favor the Graphics class method that let you draw a large number of items.  In other words, don't draw each individual particle but draw many.  You'll like DrawRectangles(), DrawLines(), DrawPath().  Unfortunately no DrawPolygons(), the one you really like, technically you could pinvoke PolyPolygon() but that's hard to get going.

If my theory is incorrect then do note that you don't need Graphics.Transform.  You can also use Matrix.TransformPoints() and Graphics.DrawPolygon().  Whether you can truly get ahead is a bit doubtful, the Graphics class doesn't use GPU acceleration directly so it never competes that well with DirectX.

Comment: Solid answer, that makes sense, and it would explain a lot about why each individual draw call is so intense. I will look into this when I get home from work and let you know how it goes, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the following would help, but it's worth trying. Instead of allocating/assigning/disposing new `Matrix`, use the preallocated `Graphics.Transform` via `Graphics` methods - [RotateTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662(v=vs.110).aspx), [ScaleTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform(v=vs.110).aspx),  [TranslateTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4(v=vs.110).aspx) (and make sure to always [ResetTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.resettransform(v=vs.110).aspx) when done).

The `Graphics` does not contain a direct equivalent of `Matrix.RotateAt` method, but it's not hard to make one

```
public static class GraphicsExtensions
{
    public static void RotateTransformAt(this Graphics g, float angle, PointF point)
    {
        g.TranslateTransform(point.X, point.Y);
        g.RotateTransform(angle);
        g.TranslateTransform(-point.X, -point.Y);
    }
}
```

Then you can update your code like this and see if that helps

```
public void RotateParticle(Graphics g, RectangleF r,
                                RectangleF rShadow, float angle,
                                Pen particleColor, Pen particleShadow)
{
    PointF shadowPoint = new PointF(rShadow.Left + (rShadow.Width / 1),
                                    rShadow.Top + (rShadow.Height / 1));
    PointF particlePoint = new PointF(r.Left + (r.Width / 1),
                                      r.Top + (r.Height / 2));
    //Angle of the shadow gets set to the angle of the particle, 
    //that way we can rotate them at the same rate
    float shadowAngle = angle;

    //rotate and draw the shadow of the Particle
    g.RotateTransformAt(shadowAngle, shadowPoint);
    g.DrawRectangle(particleShadow, rShadow.X, rShadow.Y, rShadow.Width, rShadow.Height);
    g.ResetTransform();

    //Same stuff as before but for the actual particle
    g.RotateTransformAt(angle, particlePoint);
    g.DrawRectangle(particleColor, r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
    g.ResetTransform();
}
```

Comment: This actually did help the FPS a little bit, it doesn't really help when the particles are large but when they are smaller there is a bit of a performance gain, unfortunately it's still losing 64 fps at around 1700 particles. Also the rotation is a lot different with this method, but in a good way, It looks cool :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you create an off-screen buffer to draw your particle, and have `OnPaint` simply render your off screen buffer? If you need to periodically update your screen, you can invalidate your OnScreen control/canvas, say using a `Timer`

```
Bitmap bmp;
Graphics gOff;

void Initialize() {
    bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
    gOff = bmp.FromImage();
}

private void OnPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
}

void RenderParticles() {
    foreach (var particle in Particles)
        RotateParticle(gOff, ...);
}
```

On another note, any reason to create a matrix object every time  you call `RotateParticle`? I haven't tried it, but the MSDN docs seem to suggest that get and set on `Graphics.Transform` will always create a copy. So you can keep a `Matrix` object at say class level and use it for transform. Just make sure to call `Matrix.Reset()` before using it. This might get you some performance improvement.

Comment: Would this benefit over the inbuilt double-buffering via `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);` ?

Comment: @MicahEpps Theoretically, the approach not only double buffers (which can perhaps be done by the call you mention), but controls the frequency of rendering. Practically, you will have to try out and see how much it benefits your situation.